# UART signal with resistor in series

Tags: resistors, uart

I am doing a project where I have two UART interfaces: one for a UBLOX GNSS module, and another for debugging.

Due to fact that STM32s are hard to get at the moment, I got a simple STM32F030K6T with just one UART. I found a solution and made a UART switcher by using an NPN transistor; check the picture below:

[image]

After some tests I realized that resistors R15 (the top one) and R13 are blocking the signal due to their large resistance, but with 330 Ω it worked just fine. Is there some explanation for this? How would you solve this issue with one UART interface?

Comment: Would you describe how that is supposed to work? To me it looks like you have output TX pins of two devices shorted tohether and driving single MCU RX input pin, and single MCU TX pin going to two input RX pins of devices via resistors with transistors shunting low the signal, trying to prevent the data from going to two devices simultaneously. Is this correct?

Comment: At Vcc/2 voltage on TX/RX lines, you are probably working in the 'undefined' region of voltage transition.  Not high enough to recognise as '1' and not low enough to recognise as '0'.

Comment: Can you use a MUX chip, or maybe an analog switch, or a solid state relay chip, instead of the transistors?  Ideally you'd have a series element to block or pass the signal of interest.

Comment: Pavel, how much control do you have over the timing when the UBLOX GNSS module transmits?

Comment: @Pavel - You neglected to say what your physical interface is - electrical levels, etc.  Just saying UART tells us nothing about this aspect of the design.

Comment: @Justme Right! by enabling the base of transistor I am grounding the input signal to devise in order just to senda signal to one device.

Comment: @MituRaj Transistor was not enabled while that, so it seems to me that it simply "does not like" resistance

Comment: @jonk could you please elaborate your qustion, can't really understand what do you mean with control over timing. Cheers

Comment: @SteveSh it is Mode - Asynchronus, UART TX RX, 9600 bits/s baud rate, Word length - 8 Bits, stop bits -1 (common CubeMX Asynchronus UART)

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, that's probably the proper way, however I wanted to dive into a generic components circuit world :D

Comment: Generally one would use a 2-line to 1-line data selector/multiplexer such as a 74LVC257 or equivalent, configured for the RXD and TXD lines, to reliably do your UART switching between to peripherals ...

Comment: @PavelGrigorev I only wanted to know if you can anticipate the communication from the UBLOX GNSS. Is it silent unless queried? Or does it choose its own timing as to when communication occurs?

Comment: You can still do it with generic components, you can use FETs to gate the signals.  That's all the SSRs are, back to back FETs in a SO4 package.